# Perl RegExp optional search grouping

Tags: regex, perl

Why doesn't this regexp fill the variable $1. And how can i make this possible?

```
my $txt = "abc def ghi jkl mnop";
$txt =~ /(def)?/;
```

$1 is undef

```
my $txt = "abc def ghi jkl mnop";
$txt =~ /(abc)?/;
```

This works instead.

It only works as soon as a non-optional part exists, like "\s(def)?" but this not hit the first part.

The Thing ist that i need a regexp which Returns Always true and fill $1 aso.

EDIT:
Thank you very much for your support. I'll give you a deeper insight into the problem.

In my code, $txt and the RegExp are user input. It should be given the possibility that individual words or pairs are picked out, however, regardless of the order.

My idea was to split the RegExp into order independent parts and then test each one for themselves.

example

```
  /(ghi) jkl (def)? (ABC)?/
```

Should be successful. So after splitting them into parts, and then several tests.

```
  /(ghi) jkl/ && /(def)?/ && /(abc)?/
```

For each test, the particular scalars are added to an array. For this reason (order independence), it was natural that this completely optional RegExp arise.
Please excuse my english.

Comment: Probably want `my ($match) = $txt =~ /(def)/;`. `$match` will be `def` (if there's a match) or `undef` (if there's isn't).

Comment: Probably want `my $matched = $txt =~ /def/;`. `$matched` will be true (if there's a match) or false (if there's isn't).

Comment: A regex that always matches? Like `.*`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're doing which means you need an 'always true' regex, as well capturing particular substrings? Because that sounds an awful lot like an ["XY problem"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and one that may simply be better solve in a different way, such as using the `//` operator.

Comment: Ok sorry for that less Informations. I added some additional explanations.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern `(def)?` matches either of two things: "def" or the empty string. It will try "def" first, but if it doesn't find it, it will succeed and match nothing.

It's possible to match the empty string at any location in any string, which means that it's possible to match the empty string at the very first position in your string, which means that there's no reason for the engine to look at any *later* position to see if it can find a "def" instead.

Without a better example of what you're trying to do it's hard to give advice, but you need to either modify the pattern so that it doesn't match the empty string, or provide some context to force it to attempt the match of "def" in the correct position.

Comment: I need a regexp which Return Always true, and write the founded Word in $1 if exist.

Answer (score 0):

Per a comment, you want the regex to always be true but capture the word if it exists.

This would be:

```
/^(?:.*?(def))?/s
```

Answer (score 0):

The regx used is not capturing all the expected scenarios.'(def)?' will match only 'def' char followed by 0 or more characters.
whereas, you are trying to match wherever 'def' present.

Below code will help to match 'def' in the string irrespective of the position.

```
$txt =~ /(.*)?(def)(.*)?/;

print "$2";
```

Comment: What is the difference between that and /(def)/

Comment: I think both will do the same, but in case if we want to capture the other data then it should help